# Passar id de objeto de activity para outra

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite

Estou tentando passar o `id` do meu objeto para outra `activity` utilizando `Serializable`, mas está me retornando um maldito erro que eu não sei consertar.

> **Obs:** meu objeto já implementa `serialiable`

O meu código é o seguinte:

```
if (view == btnTeste) {
        try {
            repositorioUsuario = new RepositorioUsuario(this);
            repositorioUsuario.insertUsuario(inserirUsuarioTeste());

            Intent it = new Intent(this, Parceble.class);
            it.putExtra("usuario", modeloUsuario.getId());
            startActivity(it);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(CATEGORIA, e.toString());
        }
    }
```

E na outra activity:

```
Usuario user = (Usuario) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("usuario");

    int id = 1;
    if(user != null){
        id = user.getId();
        if ( id != 0){
            Toast.makeText(Parceble.this, "id: " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

E o erro que está dando é:

> 10-07 19:23:28.031  18317-18317/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: br.com.refsoft.refsoft, PID: 18317
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.refsoft.refsoft/br.com.refsoft.refsoft.activity.Parceble}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to br.com.refsoft.refsoft.domain.Usuario
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to br.com.refsoft.refsoft.domain.Usuario
>               at br.com.refsoft.refsoft.activity.Parceble.onCreate(Parceble.java:18)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro acontece porque você não está passando um objeto `Usuario` no intent e sim apenas o seu id, que é um inteiro. Passe um objeto da classe `Usuario` que irá funcionar.

Note que será necessário fazer um "cast" (forçar mudança de tipo) de `Usuario` para `Serializable` para a operação funcionar. Por exemplo, supondo que o objeto `modeloUsuario` seja do tipo `Usuario`:

```
it.putExtra("usuario", (Serializable)modeloUsuario);
```

Agora se a sua intenção for realmente passar apenas o id e não o usuário inteiro, então o problema está na outra ponta. Na segunda Activity pegue o id usando `getIntExtra()` em vez de `getSerializableExtra()`.

Comment: Entendi! mt obrigado!!!

Answer (score 2):

Você esta passando o id, um tipo inteiro

```
it.putExtra("usuario", modeloUsuario.getId());
```

E o erro acontece nesta linha abaixo, pois você está tentando recuperar um Objeto do tipo usuario quando na verdade é um numero inteiro.

```
Usuario user = (Usuario) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("usuario");
```

Troque por

```
int id = getIntent().getIntExtra("usuario",-1);
```

Comment: Entendi! mt obrigado!!!